# Can't save image via HTML canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm having difficulties saving my canvas. I'm new to javascript so I think it could be a syntax issue.

I've got some vars saved in a function:

```
var imageView = document.getElementById("imageView");
var canvasData = imageView.toDataURL("image/png");
var postData = "canvasData="+canvasData;
```

If I add the following line it displays the image correctly:

```
imgData = $('#i').append($('<img/>', { src : canvasData }));
```

However, I have another function that I want to pass the base64 code in so I added:

```
var  the_data = "test= "+imageView.toDataURL("image/png");
```

It does print out a base64 code, but just the blank canvas (not with the drawing the user has added).

If I add the following it doesn't work:

```
  var  the_data = "test= "+canvasData;
```

What am I doing wrong?

This is a basic jsfiddle of what I'm trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/sMSeX/

Comment: Can you supply a jsfiddle of it?

Comment: I have added it in, it's a bit messy.

Comment: If you want the user force the download, you need a server-side solution.  base64 encode the image and post it to `image-download.php` where it gets translated from base64 to be an image (either with the internal image functions or by saving it to disk).

Comment: it gets posted to update.php in the code (where it does get stored to the database) - but it's currently not passing it through correctly.

Answer (score 0):

### Just a little hint from my side for uploading HTML5 canvas image data:

I am working on a project for a print-shop and had some problems due to uploading images to the server that came from an HTML5 canvas element. I was struggling at least for one hour and I did not get it to save the image correctly on my server.

I get the image data as Base64 decoded from the canvas element via

```
        var can = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas');
        var dataURL = can[0].toDataURL("image/jpg");
        //dataURL = dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
        console.log('data url: '+dataURL);
```

Once I set the 
`contentType` option of my `jQuery ajax call` to `'application/x-www-form-url-encoded'` :

```
    $.ajax({
              url: 'index.php?page=upload-image',
              type: 'post',
              contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
              //data: '{ "imageData" : "' + dataURL + '" }',
              data: dataURL,
              beforeSend: function() {
                $('.text-danger').remove();
              },
              complete: function() {

              },
              success: function(json) {
                console.log('upload complete'); 
              }
    });
```

everything went the right way and the base64-encoded data was interpreted correctly and successfully saved as an image.

---

Maybe someone helps that!